# HTTP POST  - I'm stuck

Tags: asp.net, forms, http, post

I have to POST some parameters to a URL outside my network, and the developers on the other side asked me to not use HTTP Parameters: instead I have to post my key-values in **HTTP Headers**.

The fact is that I don't really understand what they mean: I tried to use a ajax-like post, with XmlHttp objects, and also I tried to write in the header with something like

```
Request.Headers.Add(key,value);
```

but I cannot (exception from the framework); I tried the other way around, using the Response object like

```
Response.AppendHeader("key", "value");
```

and then redirect to the page... but this doesn't work, as well.

It's evident, I think, that I'm stuck there, any help?

---

**EDIT** I forgot to tell you that my environment is .Net 2.0, c#, on Win server 2003.
The exception I got is

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Operation is not supported on this platform."
  Source="System.Web"
```

This looks like it's caused by my tentative to Request.Add, MS an year ago published some security fixes that don't permit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @lassevk said, a redirect won't work.

You should use the WebRequest class to do an HTTP POST from your page or application.  There's an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the WebClient class?  An example might look like:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
        data["var1"] = "var1";
        client.UploadValues("http://somewhere.com/api", "POST", data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at HttpWebRequest.  You should be able to construct a request to the URL in question using HttpWebRequest.Method = "POST".

Answer (score 0):

You should post more information.

For instance, is this C#? It looks like it, but I might be wrong.

Also, you say you get an exception, what is the exception type and message?

In any case, you can't redirect to a page for POST, you need to submit it from the browser, not from the server redirect, so if you want to automate this, I would guess you would need to generate a html page with a form tag, with some hidden input fields, and then submit it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean they don't want you to use URL parameters (GET).  If you use http headers, it's not really querying through POST any more.

Answer (score 0):

What language/framework?

Using Python and httplib2, you should be able to do something like:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http.request(url, 'POST', headers={'key': 'value'}, body=urllib.urlencode(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Request object would only accept a certain set of predefined headers.

There's an enumeration that lists all the supported HTTP Headers too.

But I can't remember it at the moment... I'll look it up in a sec...

Answer (score 0):

I tested your scenario using 2 sample pages using XmlHttpRequest option.
Custom headers are available in the aspx page posted to, using XmlHttpRequest.

Create the following 2 pages. Make sure the aspx page is in a solution , so that you can run the in the debugger, set break point and inspect the Request.Header collection.

<html>

<head>

```
&lt; script language="javascript"&gt;

function SendRequest()
{
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open('get', 'http://localhost/TestSite/CheckHeader.aspx');
    r.setRequestHeader('X-Test', 'one');
    r.setRequestHeader('X-Test', 'two');
    r.send(null);

}
&lt; script / &gt;
```

</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" OnClick="SendRequest();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

---

CheckHeader.aspx

using System;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.UI;

public partial class CheckHeader : System.Web.UI.Page

{

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = string.Empty;
    foreach (string key in Request.Headers)
        value = Request.Headers[key].ToString();
}
```

}

Man.. This html editor sucks.. or i do not know how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

The exception I was facing yesterday was caused by my stupid try to write on the headers of the already built page.

When I started creating my Request following one of the mothods indicated here, I could write my headers.

Now I'm using the WebRequest object, as in the sample indicated by @sectrean, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx).

Thanks a lot to everybody. StackOverflow rocks :-)